# Compojure-Api return vector of schema objects

Tags: clojure, swagger, compojure-api

I have started learning Luminus framework to get into Clojure(script) for web applications. For RESTful services framework suggests using swagger/compojure-api. Examples were helpful, but I can't find any for returning collections.

Here is my model:

```
CREATE TABLE thread
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30));
```

And Conman query:

```
-- :name get-threads :? :*
-- :doc selects all threads
SELECT * FROM thread
```

For service there is a schema (it is called Threadd because of java's Thread):

```
(s/defschema Threadd {:id s/Int
                      :name s/Str})
```

Finally, in service-routes (`defapi` expression), simple GET:

```
(GET "/thread" []
      :return       Threadd
      :summary      "All threads"
      (ok  (db/get-threads)))
```

Application runs, and Swagger-UI returns this on my request(edn format):

```
{:errors "(not (map? a-clojure.lang.LazySeq))"}
```

Unfortunately, this is not obvious for me. How can I return multiple objects with schema specified? Can I return them in transit+json format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define another schema for [a sequence of](https://github.com/plumatic/schema#sequence-schema-details) threads:

```
(s/defschema Threads [Threadd])
```

and specify it as a return type of your endpoint:

```
(GET "/thread" []
      :return       Threads
      :summary      "All threads"
      (ok  (db/get-threads)))
```

You could also define it inline:

```
(GET "/thread" []
      :return       [Threadd]
      :summary      "All threads"
      (ok  (db/get-threads)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used [Threadd] option before, but with transit-writer, so error was with it. By the way, will Compojure-Api return data in format, specified by `Accept` header? Do I need transit-writer?

Comment: Yes, it should (compojure-api highlights it in the [README](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api#compojure-api---): Client negotiable formats: JSON, EDN, YAML & Transit (JSON & MessagePack)).